# Android Place Autocomplete Fragment closing on its own

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocomplete

I am trying to implement place autocomplete fragment for the first time and facing one issue with it.When ever i starts to type, after first letter it starts searching and instead of showing the results its (fragment) just disappears..
insted that i am getting is
Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

**Manifest.xml**

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4" />
```

**Xml_layout**

```
<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/Area"
    android:onClick="Onselection"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Area"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**Class**

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity implements PlaceSelectionListener {


    private static final String LOG_TAG = "PlaceSelectionListener";
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-85, -180), new LatLng(85, 180));
    private static final int REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE = 1000;
    TextView locationtext ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testtttt);
        locationtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Arear) ;

        PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);

        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build();
        autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);


    }


    public  void Onselection(View v)
    {
        try {
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder
                    (PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .setBoundsBias(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW)
                    .build(testtttt.this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException |
                GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {

    }
```

**On click fragment appears**

[image: ScreenShot]

**fragment disappears/closed on its own**

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: I leave this for future readers : https://iteritory.com/android-google-places-autocomplete-feature-using-new-places-sdk/?fbclid=IwAR3-nV3ELTilG_W79xmC-UhI9Gkag58Odykg0fW8THisBH7aNb46PCmAnz4

Answer (score 24):

This is a very intriguing experience while developing with Google APIs on Android. All that you need to do is:

1. Go to [console.developers.google.com](http://console.developers.google.com)
2. Select your project associated with the Google API Key
3. Enable google places API for android

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue, then I stumbled across this message [image] here is the link if you want to check for yourself. [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro). 
 So long story short I migrated to new APIS, whose instructions are given here. [Migrating to the new Places SDK Client](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) 

 In my case  **My map is on Fragment and search was on top of map** 

**build.gradle**

```
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

Notice the places APIs are fresh and new 1.0.0.
These APIs gave me:

**com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment** for MAP 
**com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment** for SEARCH BAR

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/f_auto_complete"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/size_search_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/map"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/map" />
```

**Fragment**

```
private fun initAutoCompleteView() {
        activity?.let { a ->
            if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
                Places.initialize(a.applicationContext, "YOUR API KEY")
            }
            fragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.f_auto_complete) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
            fragment?.let {                    
                it.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG))
                it.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
                    override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
                        Log.i("Places", place.name)

                        }
                    }

                    override fun onError(status: Status) {
                        Log.i("Places", "An error occurred: $status")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

To make life easy, I am adding imports as well just in case any of the classes don't fit together.

```
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment
import com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.listener.PlaceSelectionListener
```

Answer (score 4):

rand_mem_RAM is right.
Took me 2days googling, probably bypassed the answer because it's sooo simple.

1. Go to console.developers.google.com
2. Select your project associated with the Google API Key
3. Enable google places API for android 
   3a. Click FIRST BLUE BUTTON at top of web page, this opens next web page
   3b. Next, click SECOND BLUE BUTTON at top of next web page
   Then test your device.

Would have upvoted but can't do so as a guest.

Comment: Your Answer looks similar to the previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause is because you haven't enable billing for your project yet. That was the case with me; I tried all the solutions in this page but the place-autocomplete-fragment still keeps on closing by itself after I typed in a character.

So I literally went back to basics and went to [Places SDK for Android Getting Started page](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start) and it mentioned on that page that we need to enable billing prior to using Places SDK for Android. That solves the problem for me.

To enable billing, go to [the billing page](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable?redirect=https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start?dialogOnLoad%3Dbilling-enabled).

Comment: Place api needed billing account ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometime problem may be occur because of SHA1 fingerprint, in my case after replace debug sha1 key with release sha1 app working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you should disable restrictions on the api key. It's probably not the safest way but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the api as restricted, add the place api in the allowed API